# Laravel does not clear cache completely

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel-5.4. None of below statements clear CSS cache of Laravel project:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
...
```

and Laravel always loads old CSS files.
I had not this problem before.
How can I fix it?

Comment: It's not related to laravel. Clear your browser cache.

Comment: @MohammadHamedani i tested it on different browsers and clearing browsers cache but does not work still.

Comment: Are you used cdn like cloudflare?

Comment: no...asset files are on the same machine(local)

Comment: Are still problem with direct access to css file by url?

Comment: i changed name of the .css file and it worked(browser forces to load file with a different name from the previous one)

Comment: Maybe cache set in .htaccess file! FYI: You can add `?` at the end of url to skip caching, because browser think this is dynamic page with GET parameter.